# How to set the PWM signal to control the ESC Readytofly 40A by STM32?

Tags: stm32, pwm, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I tried to start the BLDC motor using ESC - Readytofly 40A (from Aliexpress) and STM32. I also have the switching power supply (12V, 30A).
The PWM signal working on the STM has 50Hz (I also tried to set 1kHz and 10kHz) but It doesn't work. There was only "beep" only one seconds. STM works on 3.3V but mayby ESC needs 5V signal? Has anyone got the datasheet for the Readytofly ESC 40A frm Aliexpress?

Comment: sorry, we don't "do" datasheet requests; they're [considered the same as product recommendation questions](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7336/how-to-deal-with-datasheet-requests), being off-topic. Clearly, the party selling you a device is who you ask for datasheet. If they can't deliver that, they're selling you but half a useful product.

Comment: @piotrdn you provided very poor information ... can't even find the ESC on aliexpress

Comment: The vendor has it. Ask them.